# How to execute function without any events (e.g no click, no document ready etc)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

This might sound weird, but I need it this way in order to implement something with wordpress

Basically I need to execute function without any events, so don't check for windows load, document ready, clicks etc, simply execute function,

This is what I've tired `WPCOMSharing_do();` for the function, but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: so it just performs the function when it feels like it? cuz computing doesn't work like that.

Comment: What you did does execute the function "without" any events as you're asking. It didn't work for some other reason, you have to provide more details.

Comment: Maybe what you need is just to place a `script` block containing your function call before closing `</body>` tag. That will work exactly like `$(document).ready(function() {})`, but without jQuery and any event handling.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  What happens?  Doesn't happen?  What is that function supposed to do?  Why do you not want to check for document ready?  Maybe that's the issue here.  We need ***WAY*** more details.  Right now, there is nothing we can really do to help you.  `WPCOMSharing_do();` runs a function, plain and simple.  You need to tell us why think that "doesn't work".  Do you get any errors?

Comment: If your function expects arguments, it my throw an error if you don't pass them. [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) and read [some documentation](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html) about functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that your `WPCOMSharing_do` function requires a constructed DOM. A [quick search](https://www.google.com/search?q=WPCOMSharing_do) shows that it seems to run most often after the page has loaded (often on jQuery's `ready` event). It appears that the entire point of `WPCOMSharing_do` is to ornament particular DOM elements with social-media sharing functionality.

If you try to run your function in a `<script>` tag before the rest of the page, the DOM will not have loaded. Scripts are run as the page is parsed and the DOM is constructed -- your `<script>` element likely comes before the elements needed to run that code successfully.

Your best option is to include your call to `WPCOMSharing_do` in a `<script>` tag, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Or suck it up and use `$(document).ready` :-)